# Multiple independent registration and login forms .NET Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Creating a new project in MVC 5 initiates all necessary classes to handle roles and users, which I am fine in modifying for custom properties. What I could not figure out though is, in my scenario, I have multiple different types of users e.g. Master Admins, Admins, Authors, Vendors and Tenants.

All of these have different properties as well as some shared ones. Usually, I would implement each type's username & password in their respective database tables. The ASP.NET Identity is quite tempting in a way to have a centralised store of users with the advantage of managing authentication out of the box in a easy to use manner with action results.

I have read every single result from a google search but the only solution similar to my scenario was the use of claims (which as far as I understand is not specifically made to handle this specific situation)

I am wandering if there is a way asp.net identity supports this kind of scenario?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: We had a similar situation, with some users being Admins, others being Customers, and others being Messengers and Recipients. Claims should work for your situation.

Comment: Is it like all the types of users have common properties say Email, Phonenumber and their own specific properties something like user of type Author has list of books but this property is not required for any other user type ? If you can confirm this, I can post solution implemented in my project.

Comment: Are your users really of different types (such that there are different attributes that describe each type of user), or do they just vary in the actions they are allowed to take in the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choice to meet your purpose:

1. Using a shared `ApplicationUser` class and do a separation of forms
   by the `Roles` authorization. So you can create a form with conditional inputs (limit what shows with `if(User.IsInRole("UserTypeName"))` in razor) based on User's roles using `RoleManager` or create separate views for each user type and authorize them on controller side.
2. Using simple inheritance to implement each user type based on its
   properties.

like:

```
public class CustomUser: ApplicationUser
{
    ...
}
```

You'll end up with a *Discriminator* column in your *AspNetUsers* table that will help Entity Framework identity which class it should instantiate for the row (`CustomUser` or `ApplicationUser`). Then you can either just query as normal or if you only want one particular type or another, you can use `OfType<T>` like:

```
var customUsers = db.Users.OfType<CustomUser>();
```

**Keep in mind that** any property which you add to inherited class, must be `nullable`. *You cannot require* something like a `DateTime` on `CustomUser` to be required at the database-level, because it prevents to save an `ApplicationUser`, which does not that property. However, this is only an issue at the database-level. You can still use view models to make a particular property on `CustomUser` required *from a front-end perspective*.

Comment: I think this approach is better but please extend your answer with an example if possible as I need to mark an answer in couple of hours and I want future comers to have as much information as possible.

Comment: I have marked this as an answer since it gives a better flexibility of creating app users however, current/future readers of this post should know that at the moment I am at quite a novice level regarding this subject and will review this once I feel myself pro enough. Otherwise please feel free to comment.

Comment: @KemalEmin I like your manner to build useful things. regards.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Claims, I would recommend Roles. If you are unsure how to do this read on.

If you created a default Web application with MVC, then Entity Framework is already installed.  Assuming you have used Code first migrations, then EF will also have already set up your database for you.

In the process it will have added a folder Migrations with a class Configuration.cs.  This file contains a method Seed, which is where we will make changes.

First add the following usings to Configuration.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Models; // assuming you have kept to the defaults
```

Add the following code in the Seed function:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(userManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
```

A little tip here.  By default MVC5 sets up a user system which is Email based.  Infuriatingly, also by default the UserManager checks that UserName (identical to Email) does not contain special characters (including @).  Hence the need to turn this off.

To add a Role, we simply do:

```
context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Name, new IdentityRole { Name = "MyRoleName" });
context.SaveChanges();
```

To add a new user to a role

```
if (!context.Users.Any(t => t.Email == "anyone@anywhere.com"))
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "anyone@anywhere.com", Email = "anyone@anywhere.com" };
    userManager.Create(user, "Password#1");
    context.SaveChanges();
    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "MyRoleName");
}
```

To add an existing user to a Role:

```
var existingUser = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == "anyone@anywhere.com").FirstOrDefault();
userManager.AddToRoles(existingUser.Id, "MyRoleName");
```

To apply these changes, simply run update-database in the package manager window.

Now that you have Users with Roles you can restrict any action you like, using the Authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="MyRoleName")]
```

These attributes can be set at class level (to enable/disable the entire Controller), or for individual actions.  To set multiple roles, use:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="MyRoleName, MyOtherRole")]
```

Note this means that anyone who has either role is duly authorized.  If you want to authorize only users that have both roles then you must do:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="MyRoleName")]
[Authorize(Roles ="MyOtherRole")]
```

As well as using Roles to restrict access to your Controllers and Actions, you can also use them to show/hide items in the View.  For example, using razor:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
   <p><a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Administration")">Admin Area</a></p>
}
```

This has the advantage the non-Admin, users do not notice what they are missing!

Answer (score 0):

First I want you to create all desired Roles e.g tenants etc

Then create ViewModels like  **RegisterViewModel.cs** for multiple independent registration of admins,tenants etc.

Then use action method **Register** of Controller **AccountController.cs** and if you want user to have selected role you can use this single line

```
    var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, "Tenants");
```

Now use Views Like **Register.cshtml** to complete process.

Let me explain with code.Create a ViewModel class Vendor.cs

```
      public class VendorViewModel
 {
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }}
```

Now Create an actionmethod Vendor in AccountController.cs

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateVendor()
        {

            return View();
        }
         [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
           [HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Vendor(VendorViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
         //Add Vendor role to user
           var role = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, "Vendor");
 }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Now Create View Vendor.cshtml

```
          @model IdentitySample.Models.VendorViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Vendor";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Vendor", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Vendor" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Create more like these whenever you need those forms.

Comment: can you extend this answer a little more please?